# Change values from a array while iterating

Tags: php, arrays

the array:

`('abc', 'def', 'xyz')`

```
foreach($arr as $item)
  // change $item here
```

Can I do this without creating a intermediate array?

Comment: ...although in almost all cases I'd argue that reducing side-effects only increases program readability...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a reference.

```
foreach($arr as &$item)
```

Comment: can explain your solution with an example?
I was not able to get clear idea